# Use Robocopy to copy files from source that have changed or are new when compared to a specified folder to a 3rd folder

Tags: rsync, robocopy, windows-server-2012-r2, cwrsync

I have a large folder of files that needs to be transferred to a remote site. This folder is currently 10GB total, but contains lots of much smaller files.

Rather than copying the entire 10GB each time, we'd like to massively reduce the data transfer size to be only the files that are new or changed. We plan to do this like so:

`SOURCE_DIR` is the folder that has all the files and is up-to-date.

`COMPARE_DIR` is a directory "clone" of the folder at the remote end. It is basically all the files up to the last time files were transferred.

`TRANSFER_DIR` is an empty folder that (we hope) ROBOCOPY can place files that are new or changed in `SOURCE_DIR` when compared with `COMPARE_DIR` into.

An example:

`SOURCE_DIR` has 4 files: 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, 4.txt

`COMPARE_DIR` has 3 of those files: 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt

The ROBOCOPY command would compare `SOURCE_DIR` with `COMPARE_DIR` and see that 4.txt isn't in `COMPARE_DIR` so copies it into `TRANSFER_DIR`

`TRANSFER_DIR` then only has 4.txt file in it which we can copy up to the remote end and place in the folder making it the same as our `SOURCE_DIR` this end.

This can be done with rsync using the --compare-dest=DIR argument, but as this is Windows, I'd rather not have to install rsync unless I need to.